# Joomla 3 plugin to override class JMenuSite

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I'm trying to override a class JMenuSite
"libraries/cms/menu/site.php".
I created a plugin system jmenusite.php

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

class plgSystemJmenusite extends JPlugin{

    public function  onAfterRoute () {
        require_once(JPATH_SITE.'/plugins/system/jmenusite/site.php');
    }
}
?>
```

I copied the files site.php in the folder of the plugin.

Joomla performs the original class and then gives me error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class JMenuSite

How can I override the existing class?

Answer (score -1):

Check whether this class name is already in use or not. If it's there choose another class name. We can't use same class name twice when another plugin is activated with same class name.

Comment: Even though you can check if the class name is already in use or not, it does not answer to question about how to override it.

Comment: What is the need to override when we can extend the class?